# If a file is listed in a cache manifest but not placed into the page's document, will it be cached?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, html5-appcache, offline-caching

I have a bunch of files listed in a cache `manifest`. Firefox's network tab shows the page being loaded and cached but the files listed do not show ever being loaded or cached. They are not added to the page until someone clicks a proper button and then they (videos) are placed into the document and loaded by JavaScript.

Will all the HTML5 compliant browsers still cache all files in a manifest, or do they need to be added to the document at load time?

MANIFEST

```
CACHE MANIFEST

# Manifest last updated: 2015-09-13 13:05:31

CACHE:
stylesheets/desktop.css
stylesheets/tablet.css
scripts/script.js
videos/test.mp4
```

MAIN PAGE CALL TO MANIFEST

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="manifest.appcache">
```

The video is inserted in JavaScript when the user clicks to play it. Do I need to add it to the page during load to make it cached?

Answer (score 0):

The browser will cache any file in a manifest whenever that file is first requested. Files in manifests don't need to be loaded at the time of the document load event.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm a little confused though.  *"The browser will cache any file in a manifest whenever that file is first requested."* - The file is not requested until the JavaScript calls it. By that time, they might already be offline. So will it be cached and available at that time? Or is that request by JavaScript when the browser tries to cache it?

Comment: Request meaning the network request. If the browser is offline, the network request to get the file will fail, and the file won't be retrieved or cached. The browser will try the network request every time to get the file until it's cached.

Comment: thanks again. So what you're saying is that the following scenario will result in **not** getting the file? **1.** load the page (browser reads manifest) **2.** go offline **3.** click button so JavaScript tries to load the video file that was mentioned in manifest ... *Am I correct that will result in the video not loading?*

Comment: The video has to be loaded by the browser at least one time before the device goes offline if the video is going to be cached and available offline. Note that the browser may still decide to purge the video from the cache at any time in order to free up storage space on the device.

Comment: OK, thank you. Is there any other way to store the video to protect against that purging?

Comment: You cannot store files or data in a way that the browser can never automatically clear. Browsers will always attempt to free up storage space if it becomes necessary, and storage limits vary quite a bit depending on platform and usage (more on that at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/). If it's vital that users have *permanent* offline access to large media assets, you should strongly consider packaging your app in something like a Chrome Web App or Cordova.